アコーディオンを開いてheightが変わってもmasonryが反応しない（高さが変わらず被る）
masonryの実装はなんとかなったのですが、アコーディオンを開いても高さが変わらずに被ってしまいます。
アコーディオンは.clickで機能させています。
<section id="content">
  <div class="grid locais-cards">
  <!--governance-->
  <div id="governance" class="grid-item cell">
    <div class="masonry-content">
      <div class="content-ttl">1. </div>
      <div class="item-box">
        <ol class="item-list">
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li class="dac"><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li class="dac"><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li class="under">
              <p class="nav-open">アコーディオン部分</p>
              <nav class="item-accordion">
                <ol>
                  <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
                </ol>
              </nav>
          </li>
          <li class="dac"><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li class="dac under">
              <p class="nav-open">アコーディオン部分</p>
              <nav class="item-accordion">
                <ol>
                  <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
              </ol>
              </nav>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div id="sd-info" class="grid-item cell">
    <div class="masonry-content">
      <div class="content-ttl">タイトル</div>
      <div class="item-box">
        <ol class="item-list">
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="fse-support" class="grid-item cell">
    <div class="masonry-content">
      <div class="content-ttl">3. FSE サポート情報</div>
      <div class="item-box">
        <ol class="item-list">
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div id="Document" class="grid-item cell">
    <div class="masonry-content">
      <div class="content-ttl">タイトル</div>
      <div class="item-box">
        <ol class="item-list">
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
          <li><a href="">テキスト</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var $grid = jQuery('.grid').imagesLoaded(function(){
   $grid.masonry({
   itemSelector: '.grid-item',
   horizontalOrder: true
   });
   });

   </script>

</section>

js
$(function(){
  //クリックで動く
  $('.nav-open').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $(this).parents('li').toggleClass('active');
    $(this).next('nav').slideToggle();
  });
});

